# Connected 0-measure set does not contain line segments

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is there a set which is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n,n>1$, is connected, has a positive area (Lebesgue measure) and does not contain any single line segment?

Comment: Suggestion: try reproducing the construction of the Smith-Volterra-Cantor set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) built over a [fat Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) has positive measure.

Comment: @bof: I don’t know; that’s getting into geometric topology, which never really appealed to me.